# Lisp code (s-expression) formatter

Tags: emacs, formatting, lisp, textmate

jSIMLIB checker prints out s-expression code that is essentially lisp code

```lisp
(set-option :print-success false) 
(set-logic QF_LIA) 
(declare-fun RETURN () Int)
(declare-fun refs_1_SYMINT () Int)
(declare-fun flags_2_SYMINT () Int)
(assert+ ( and ( or ( and (/= flags_2_SYMINT 0) (and (= RETURN flags_2_SYMINT)) ) ( and (/= refs_1_SYMINT 0) (and (= flags_2_SYMINT 0)) (and (= RETURN refs_1_SYMINT)) ) ( and (and (= refs_1_SYMINT 0)) (and (= flags_2_SYMINT 0)) (and (= RETURN 100)) ) ) ( not ( or ( and (/= flags_2_SYMINT 0) (and (= RETURN flags_2_SYMINT)) ) ( and (/= refs_1_SYMINT 0) (and (= flags_2_SYMINT 0)) (and (= RETURN refs_1_SYMINT)) ) ( and (and (= refs_1_SYMINT 0)) (and (= flags_2_SYMINT 0)) (and (= RETURN 10)) ) ) ) ) )
(check)
(exit)
```

How can I format the code, preferable with emacs or TextMate? For example:

```lisp
(set-option :print-success false) 
(set-logic QF_LIA) 
(declare-fun RETURN () Int)
(declare-fun refs_1_SYMINT () Int)
(declare-fun flags_2_SYMINT () Int)
(assert 
  (and  
    (and 
      (and  
        (distinct  flags_2_SYMINT 0)  
        (=  RETURN flags_2_SYMINT))
      (=  refs_1_SYMINT refs1_1_SYMINT)
      (=  flags_2_SYMINT flags1_2_SYMINT))
    (not 
      (and  
        (distinct  flags_2_SYMINT 0) 
        (=  RETURN flags_2_SYMINT))))) 
(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In GNU Emacs you can use `indent-pp-sexp`.

Set the cursor before the s-expression to pretty-print and type `c-u m-x indent-pp-sexp`.

Answer (score 9):

The `pp` function can print things out nicely but may not exactly match the formatting you want.

Here's one line from your question:

```
(pp '(assert+ ( and ( or ( and (/= flags_2_SYMINT 0) (and (= RETURN flags_2_SYMINT)) ) ( and (/= refs_1_SYMINT 0) (and (= flags_2_SYMINT 0)) (and (= RETURN refs_1_SYMINT)) ) ( and (and (= refs_1_SYMINT 0)) (and (= flags_2_SYMINT 0)) (and (= RETURN 100)) ) ) ( not ( or ( and (/= flags_2_SYMINT 0) (and (= RETURN flags_2_SYMINT)) ) ( and (/= refs_1_SYMINT 0) (and (= flags_2_SYMINT 0)) (and (= RETURN refs_1_SYMINT)) ) ( and (and (= refs_1_SYMINT 0)) (and (= flags_2_SYMINT 0)) (and (= RETURN 10)) ) ) ) ) ))
```

output is:

```
(assert+
 (and
  (or
   (and
    (/= flags_2_SYMINT 0)
    (and
     (= RETURN flags_2_SYMINT)))
   (and
    (/= refs_1_SYMINT 0)
    (and
     (= flags_2_SYMINT 0))
    (and
     (= RETURN refs_1_SYMINT)))
   (and
    (and
     (= refs_1_SYMINT 0))
    (and
     (= flags_2_SYMINT 0))
    (and
     (= RETURN 100))))
  (not
   (or
    (and
     (/= flags_2_SYMINT 0)
     (and
      (= RETURN flags_2_SYMINT)))
    (and
     (/= refs_1_SYMINT 0)
     (and
      (= flags_2_SYMINT 0))
     (and
      (= RETURN refs_1_SYMINT)))
    (and
     (and
      (= refs_1_SYMINT 0))
     (and
      (= flags_2_SYMINT 0))
     (and
      (= RETURN 10)))))))
```